# Principal get lost after one request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, userprincipal

I have the function `AffiliateLogin` in a controller that sets the `Principal`.
the row `principal.User = user;` is actually the one storing the Principal.
But after I redirect to another controller, and test my `AuthorizeWithRolesAttribute` attribute, the principal is reset.
This is one second after the login, you can see the red arrow:

[image]

this is the function that stores it.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

```
public JsonResult AffiliateLogin(string email, string password)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Affiliate user = api.GetUserByCredencials<Affiliate>(email, password);
                if (user != null)
                {

                     IIdentity identity = new UserIdentity(true,user.Email);
                    UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(identity, new string[] {"Affiliate"});
                    principal.User = user;

                    HttpContext.User = principal;
                    return Json("Login success");
                }
            }
            return Json("Fail To Login");
        }
```

Comment: How is AffiliateLogin called?

Comment: @ChrisBint - its an action: localhost:5555/Api/User/AffiliateLogin/?email=test@gmail.com&password=pass

Answer (score 0):

The principal property won't survive between web requests. You had to set it again in the next request after redirection.

Comment: Please explain. I don't undrstand

Comment: the scope of the context is per request. so each request is a new `httpcontext`.

Comment: @JasonMeckley - So what is the solution

Comment: You can use Session to preserve the object across requests.

Comment: set the user property for each request. usually in a httphandler or actionfilter. you can also use the builtin authentication providers to handle this for you. (search asp.net forms authentication and universal/simple membership provider)

Comment: @JasonMeckley - is that a good way to store the principal? `Session.Add("principal", principal);` ? thanks

Comment: No, there is already a mechanism to store the user HttpContext.User. use this to store/retreive the user

Answer (score 0):

If your doing doing custom authentication/forms authentication you should call

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
```

The next http from the  browser with that  cookie , Asp.net will process the cookie and set 
the current claims principal. So you can check

```
var principal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;  //normally this reverts to Thread.CurrentPrincipal,
```

Here is a good place to learn a bit more
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.current